# Primefaces components not correctly displayed in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, primefaces

i made a little registration form using JSF 2 and Primefaces 2.2 and deployed it on jboss as 6 on localhost.

I am using the primefaces lightbox

```
<p:lightBox iframe="true" width="80%" height="80%">  
    <h:outputLink value="http://www.google.de" title="test">  
        <h:outputText value="test"/>  
    </h:outputLink>  
</p:lightBox>
```

In Firefox there is no problem.

Opera works too.

In Chrome 9.0.5 the lightbox opens and stays black. No page is rendered within the lightbox.
Also the password component of primefaces showing how strong the current typed password is works only in firefox and opera.

I configured chrome to block all cookies and javascript. I added exceptions for both like this:

```
[*.]localhost
```

I also configured chrome to not block any cookies or javascript at all but it reminds broken.

Using Chrome, the primefaces showcase (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lightboxHome.jsf) works!

The windows hosts file looks ok too:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See FAQ #3;

http://www.primefaces.org/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

The view tag needs contentType to be set for some PrimeFaces components to work in Chrome.

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
```